# Software for combining audio and video

Tags: windows, audio

I recorded a video but it had no sound, so I want to add sound, audio into the video, of courses the sound, audio will be at a specific time not the whole video will have sound, audio (The video is 10:00 minutes, so I want to add sound at 4:00 and 6:00, and the rest of the video don't have sound). I have heard about the built-in video software on Windows, is this work? If its not, is there any easy software that can do my requirements? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Movie Maker can do this (or the Photos app, depending on which version of Windows you're on). It's not the best program, but it works. There's a guide on using Windows Movie Maker to do that [here](https://www.iskysoft.com/video-editing/how-to-combine-video-and-audio-in-windows-movie-maker.html) about halfway down, and using the Photos app [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/combine-audio-and-video/).

You can also do it on the command line with [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) which may be more efficient once you're used to it. An example would be `ffmpeg.exe -y -i the-video.mp4 -itsoffset 00:40:00 -i the-audio.mp3 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -preset ultrafast -async 1 output-file.mp4` ([source](https://superuser.com/questions/708125/add-audio-at-specific-time-in-video-using-ffmpeg)).